# Empty checkbox field returning null instead of 0 after updating from Laravel 5.4 to 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I recently updated my app from laravel 5.4 to 5.7. After updating, I noticed I was getting the following error when submitting a form with an unchecked checkbox:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'mature_enabled' cannot be null

In other words, instead of returning **0**,

```
    Auth::user()->update([
        'mature_enabled' => $request->get('mature_enabled'),
```

returns **null** on an empty checkbox. But a checked checkbox will return **1**.

This is what the field looks like in blade:

```
    <div class="{{ $errors->has('mature_enabled') ? ' has-error' : '' }} settingsCheckbox"> 
        <label for="mature_enabled">Show mature content. Adults Only (18+).</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mature_enabled" value="1"
               @if (Auth::user()->mature_enabled  == 1)
               checked="checked"
               @endif
               >      
    </div>
```

Why is this happening? I haven't changed anything at all since updating Laravel so I can only imagine this is a laravel issue.

Comment: Check in your database that mature_enabled field is nullable or not. If it is not nullable then, try to make it null and check the error. If you want, you can give the required validation to mature_enabled field.

Comment: You could do `intval($request->get('mature_enabled'))` and force the result to always be an integer value, or use an `is_null` to check the value and replace it with the correct one

Comment: share your migration file

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

Because `Request::get`'s signature is `get($key, $default = null)`, so when the checkbox isn't checked it won't be sent at all and `get('mature_enabled')` will return `null`.

> I haven't changed anything at all since updating Laravel so I can only imagine this is a laravel issue.

Actually, no, Laravel's `Request::get()` just calls Symfony's one, and it's not recommended to use it:

```
* This method belongs to Symfony HttpFoundation and is not usually needed when using Laravel.
*
* Instead, you may use the "input" method.
```

So, you can fix your code this way:

```php
$request->input('mature_enabled', false)
```

Or, if don't use validation and you'd want to ensure it's bool:

```php
!!$request->input('mature_enabled')
```